# reusing worker threads pthreads

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I have run into a situation with pthreads.Consider the following script:

```
<?php
class W extends \Worker {
    public function run()
    {
    echo "worker started\n";
    }
}
clasds S extends \Stackable {
    public function run()
    {
    echo "stackable executed\n";
    }
}
class x{
    protected $workers;
    protected $i;
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->workers = array();
    $this->i = 0;
    }

    public function go()
    {
    $thread = $this->spawn();
    $j = new S;
    $thread->stack($j);
    //$thread->shutdown();
    }

    public function spawn()
    {
    $this->i !== 0 ? $n=$this->i++ : $n=$this->i;
    $thread = new W;
    $this->workers[$n] = $thread;
    $thread->start();
    return $thread; 
    }
}
$exe = new x;
$exe->go();
```

php crashes.2 ways to solve the issue, either:
uncommenting
    $w->shutdown();
which means the workers one creates are not reusable, or commenting out 
    $this->c[$n] = $w;
which means not saving workers in an array.
I do not understand what is going on here.must one call shutdown on a worker?why does attempting to store 
the worker in an array lead to a crash?

Comment: $thread = new W;
    $this->workers[$n] = $thread;

Comment: also, http://php.net/Pool ... try that, and see documents in README.md on github ;)

Comment: oop sorry that was a typo.it still doesn't work.I have observed the same thing in the pooling.php example. one has either to call shutdown immediately after stacking or not save the worker in an array.otherwise leads to a crash.

Comment: Also tried referencing and splObjectStorage.same results.

Comment: Please post the _actual_ code giving you a problem.

Comment: I have edited the question.the code above demonstrates the problem.The problem addressed in the question also applies to the example provided in pooling.php.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782 read it all, specifically answered by pitfalls section, but read it all ;)

Comment: I've read through it all, paying especially close attention to the pitfalls section.The crash does not appear to be a segfault, as neither the worker nor the stackable are modified before execution, nor indeed after. Referencing the worker to a variable in the class scope causes the crash, but local variables don't. Perhaps something in the class modifies the worker, but I don't see what that could be.So, long story short, why does referencing the worker cause php to crash ?Does one have to call shutdown on a worker after stacking ?